# Counteracting pull up resistors in a MAX15162 to prevent turn on until the system stabilizes

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, pulldown

I am planning to use the new MAX15162 smart circuit breaker / eFuse to turn on and off a circuit and protect from short circuit / over current. Problem is I failed to notice that the enable pins have internal pullup resistors which means that it will immediately turn on when the system is turned on rather than waiting for an enable pull up from the system MCU.

My idea was to use a pull down resistor to counter and effectively sink the internal pullups which can then be overcome by the MCU.

I can't see why this wouldn't work but was hoping for some perspective as I am new at this.

A little more about the system, it is a midpoint device that can provide 24v or 48v on two different rails and the 24v or 48v could come up before the MCU 3.3v signal in some situations so I don't want both of the IC's to turn on both of their outputs at the same time.

R20,R21,R26, and R27 are the resistors that I am proposing and I guess don't know for sure how to calculate.

[image: Part of my schematic]

[image: From https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX15162.pdf]

[image: Block Diagram for the MAX15162]

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/protection-control/protection-ics/MAX15162.html

Comment: Use an inverter to drive power on reset with small cap across R to ensure input drives to appropriate state

Comment: Use Tony's approach to disable EN1 and EN2 during power up.  Also, it is a good idea to link to part darasheets in your question.

Comment: Thank you SSR, I had put it as a caption to the datasheet image I included but didn't realize that just resulted in an alt tag on the image.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I thought of that but I would need four of them and three optocouplers because of the the power rails and the fact that any single one could come up first. The resistors are just so much simpler. Is there a reason not to do that other than wasting power?

I guess technically I had used a comparator. I have never used an inverter but I assume that is probably what makes a comparator work. Thank you for giving me another building block. imgur.com/DQQuQf2

Answer (score 0):

They didn't mention the value of the pull-up resistors, but they stated the maximum pull-up current to be 12μA if the EN input is at 0.4V, which is also the maximum voltage level for it to be recognized as low state. This is of course assuming that an external resistor is pulling the input down, because else no pull-up current would flow.
This means we can conveniently calculate the highest possible value of the pull-down resistor as follows:
\$R_{PD} = \frac{V_{EN\_IL}}{I_{EN\_PUP}} = \frac{0.4V}{12\mu A} = 33.3k\Omega \$
To be on the safe side, use something a bit lower, for example 22kΩ. That should still be no problem for your MCU to pull up again.

Comment: Thank you Marco, I knew it had to do with that pull up current but wasn't sure exactly how to put that together. Thank you for the formula. I'll see if anyone else chimes in and then I'll probably just draw it that way and try it on a board.

Comment: If 12uA is max or nominal then this is precisely the best answer after it is corrected to say (Vdd-0.4)/12uA~. For a fuse controller, I guess the added load is a no-brainer

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Why would it be Vdd-0.4? I'm calculating the external pull-down resistor (R_PD) through which the 12uA current of the internal pull-up flows to ground. The maximum voltage at the input pin to be recognized as "low" is 0.4V, so that's what the resistor divider is calculated for. Don't you agree?

Comment: Does it say 12uA current source or 12uA when pulled down from Vdd to 0.4V? So you want the voltage drop internally to estimate the Rpu. I would think its a polysilicon R, so you want voltage drop internal not external.

Comment: The datasheet states that the internal pull-up (source) current of the EN pin is 12uA max. Assuming that the internal control logic is high-impedance, the same current must flow through the external pull-down resistor I'd argue.

Comment: Ok but pullup current at what voltage? All or 0.4 only?

Comment: At 0.4V, that is the "EN_ Pullup Current" parameter at the bottom of the datasheet screenshot. The current should be lower at higher input voltages, which is also indicated by the 1uA figure of the the "EN_ Input Current" parameter just above.

Comment: Ven @ 0uA is low so seems like a current source with 1.25V 74HC xx logic threshold OK

Answer (score 0):

- use a 1k pulldown R and after protype test, measure Ven and use KVL to determine higher value if desired but not necessary.

I presume the uC driver will be high Z input until defined as Output and POR to decide what state you want to be ON or not.